# Spring JPA - Hibernate not adding columns to the table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I saw so many answers here, but couldn't find the one that could solve my problem.

problem:  When I add the field in my entity class, hibernate does not update it in mysql automatically so I have to do it manually which is annoying.

Here is my application.properties content:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mysql?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version are you using? Try with `spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`

Comment: @Asgar I'm using v2.6.1   spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update  is for older versions and it does not work too (I tried it earlier)

Answer (score 0):

I need to see your entity class but if you want to update or add anything to your database it's better to use migration tools ( for example flyway )